# Iterating through a data frame and grouping values in a range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a python data frame of weekly data like this :

```
Week Val
1    11
2    11
3    11
4    11
5    9
6    9
7    9
8    9
```

I would like create an output table like this:

```
Week 1 Week 2 Val
1      4      11
5      8      9
```

Apologies, I am quite new to python and its iterative tools. I am not sure how to solve this problem.
I tried to match using the previous row columns but I do not think how to go further:

```
df['Match'] = df['Val'].eq(df['Val'].shift(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to groupby the consecutive blocks of `Val`. So you can use `cumsum` on the non-zero differences to get the block:

```
blocks = df['Val'].ne(df['Val'].shift(1)).cumsum()

(df.groupby(blocks, as_index=False)
   .agg(Week1=('Week','min'), Week2=('Week','max'), Val=('Val', 'first'))
)
```

Or you can chain:

```
(df.groupby(df['Val'].ne(df['Val'].shift(1)).cumsum(), as_index=False)
   .agg(Week1=('Week','min'), Week2=('Week','max'),Val=('Val', 'first'))
)
```

Output:

```
   Week1  Week2  Val
0      1      4   11
1      5      8    9
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get the follwoing error: DataFrame' object is not callable